# Concrete5 – Implicit Aliases for the Subpages of an Alias

Tags: internationalization, url-routing, concrete5

I use the internationalization module for a new project. But for a one page and it's subpages I want to handle the translation manualy coded in the pagetype. There will be thousands of subpages, so I want to avoid actually creating an alias for each of them.

For example, if there is a page with an URL like this:

```
domain.com/en/section-to-be-aliased/a-sub-page
```

... it should also be reachable via

```
domain.com/de/section-to-be-aliased/a-sub-page
```

... while there is only an alias for the superior page, called "section-to-be-aliased" here.

What would you suggest to be the cleanest way to do that, keeping all caching-functionality alife?

My first approache would be to inherit the `Concrete5_Library_Request` class and overwrite the `function getRequestedPage()`.
But I'm wondering if there is a simpler solution. Also i recognized, that in the sitemap the alias shows the number of subpages of it's original ... which suggests that they are already accessable via the alias? Well I tried the corresponding URLs and they didn't work.

Comment: I would first try the Library_Request route. However, you should also consider the building of a sitemap. Ie, what happens when you add the autonav block. The correct solution will handle both sides (the request) but also reach deep enough down that it'll mimic the full sitemap, too...

Comment: Hey James, thanks for the hint. There will be a custom navigation for this section, working with different filters and sortations. So no need to show the pages in the autonav, but still there are probably some C5 functionalities that need to be kept alive somehow – I'll report my results here.